# problema con decimales 2.01 es 2.009

Tags: c++, c++17

Tengo un problema con decimales, quiero comprobar cuantos 0.01 existen en mi variable paso un valor 2.01 pero aparece 2.00999 y cuando le resto el dos no alcanza al 0.01 entonces no puedo saber si existe esa décima o no, como solucionaría ese problema? se me ocurre dividir por 0.00999 pero no creo que sea la mejor forma.

```
float cambio = 0; int cantidad = 0;
std::cin>>cambio; // ingreso 2.01 pero obtiene 2.00999 (un numero periódico)
cambio -= cantidad*2; // aquí elimino el dos
cantidad = cambio/0.01; // pero al ser 0.009 (un numero periódico) no alcanza a ser dividido por 0.01
```

edito: lo he solucionado de la siguiente forma pero no creo que sea correcto lo que estoy haciendo.

```
cantidad = (int)((cantidad*1000)/9);
```

Comment: Te sugiero colocar el fragmento de código que presenta problema y así algún usuario pueda evaluar el codigo y obtengas una respuesta.

Comment: Podría ser un problema de precisión, que tipo de variables son cambio y cantidad.?

Comment: Los números flotantes tienen problema de precisión señalado en el estandar IEEE 754 : https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_coma_flotante